# There is no spawnl function in python 2.6?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I just noticed that my old codes written in python 2.5 does not work now.  I am in python 2.6 btw.

```
>>> os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT,"setup.exe")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\python26\lib\os.py", line 612, in spawnl
    return spawnv(mode, file, args)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>>>
```

Any clue? or do you have any working sample of os.spawn* with NOWAIT option.

Update:

Even I put full path in os.spawnl(), Its still error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thrope is right about `subprocess` being preferred.  But the spawn* stuff is still there in [2.6](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=spawn#os.spawnl).  In fact, you can see that in your error message.  Your first arg seems to be valid.  I'd check the second arg, which is the path.

Comment: I would check the arguments as I don't get this error when running on a OS/machine with no setup.exe

Comment: I have setup.exe on same folder, I think I am sure.

Comment: but I dont have anything to pass setup.exe because Its just invoking installer. even I put blank string "", its not working.

Comment: Maybe the current working directory isn't in the environment's search path?  But that stuff is beyond my ken for Windows.

Comment: Imm, I tested by putting in environment variable, still not working, and this is part of program auto update options, so I think I shouldnt mess up with user's environment variables.

Comment: The same error S. Mark describes happened to me, and I've only been able to work around it by using subprocess. Shame.

Answer (score 5):

I got it work by adding DUMMY parameter finally, a bit funky though

This is not working

```
os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT,"Setup.exe")
```

This is also not working

```
os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT,"Setup.exe","")
```

But this is working

```
os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT,"Setup.exe","DUMMY")
```

Thanks all anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I think its recommended to use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module these days rather than the `os.spawn*` functions. (I can't reproduce your problem, but I'm not on windows).

Answer (score 2):

`os.spawnl()` requires full path to executable, while `os.spawnlp()` uses PATH environment variable to find it.

**Update**: Also it's common error to use unescaped backslashes in the path literal (try printing it to see whether it's interpreted right).

Answer (score 2):

A Google search brings up [this page](http://www.openemm.org/forums/ftopic1012.html) about the same problem happening when there is a space in the Python installation path. I couldn't reproduce it here, but maybe it's the problem?

In any case, [according to MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7zt1y878%28VS.80%29.aspx) this error value (EINVAL) should only be returned if the mode argument is invalid, which isn't the case here.